# Tkinter GUI stops responding when launched

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, popen

I am working on making a GUI which I can use to select arguments like script, and port number to pass to my script.
My code is working and I am getting answers from my interpreter but for some unknown reason the GUI stops responding after displaying the result of the running

I tried so many ways to run the interpreter (popen, os.system, popen+thread ...) but still the same result, it always stops responding and I have to force it to stop and kill the process because it keeps using the port.

```
def interpreter():
    que2.put_nowait(queue[0])
    b = que2.get()
    a = que1.get()
    c = 'python C:\\workspace\\Project_Interpreter\\Tool-v1.0.py -s %s %s' % (b, a)
    ps=sp.Popen(c , stdout=PIPE)

    def stdoutprocess(o):
        while True:
            stdoutdata = o.stdout.readline()
            if stdoutdata:
                sys.stdout.write(stdoutdata)
            else:
                break
    t = threading.Thread(target=stdoutprocess,args=(ps,))
    t.start()
    ps.wait()
    t.join()
    print "Return code", ps.returncode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what was the problem.In fact I am putting the program on hold waiting for nothing and then I am making the thread wait also, so the program crashes.
So long story short, what should be done is remove the two lines

```
ps.wait()
t.join()
```

and then it will work properly and you may also retrieve answers in real time !